# Remove line breaks from start and end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I noticed that trim() does not remove new line characters from the start and end of a string, so I am trying to accomplish this with the following regex:

```
return str.replace(/^\s\n+|\s\n+$/g,'');
```

This does not remove the new lines, and I fear I am out of my depth here.

**EDIT**
The string is being generated with ejs like so

```
go = ejs.render(data, { 
    locals: { 
        format() {
            // 
        }
    } 
});
```

And this is what go is, but with a few empty lines before. When I use go.trim() I still get the new lines before.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="Out" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in" margin-top="1in" margin-bottom="0.5in" margin-left="0.75in" margin-right="0.75in">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="1in" margin-bottom="0.25in"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="1in"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="0.25in"/>
            <fo:region-start extent="0in"/>
            <fo:region-end extent="0in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Out" initial-page-number="1" force-page-count="no-force">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block font-size="14pt" text-align="center">ONLINE APPLICATION FOR SUMMARY ADVICE</fo:block>
            <fo:block font-size="13pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center">Re:
                SDF, SDF
            </fo:block>

        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font="10pt Helvetica">

            .. removed this content

        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: Try: `/^[\s\n]+|[\s\n]+$/`

Comment: What `trim` do you use? The standard one does. Also, please show us your string, maybe you have some weird (invisible) characters in there.

Comment: Really `Javascript` `trim()` does not remove `newlines`? But it should remove all the `whitespaces` from the ends? And `newline` should be one of them. `\n` is a subelement of `\s`.

Comment: @elclanrs: linebreaks are included in `\s`

Comment: @Bergi: Oh right!, `\t\r` as well I guess?

Comment: Can we get clarification here?  does `trim` get rid of newline characters

Comment: @LeeBlake `trim()` removed newline characters at the end of my String (bash output from execSync) so there must be something strange going on with his string.

Comment: Just to confirm - `trim()` **does** remove spaces, tabs, `\n`, `\r`, etc. This was standardized in 2009 (ES5). So if you remember it not removing newlines, you're probably old like me.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nBk7j/).

Comment: I solved it changing from this answer to `str.replace(/^\n|\n$/g, '');`

Comment: This also removes leading spaces.

Comment: How can we do the same thing with PHP?

Comment: `str.replace(/(^\s*(?!.+)+\n+)|(\s+(?!.+)+\n*$)/g, "")` will remove all trailing whitespace except the first and last line that contains any character.

Comment: Above example had a bug. This should work: `str.replace(/(^\s*(?!.+)\n+)|(\n+\s+(?!.+)$)/g, "")`

Comment: Your solution removes too much

Comment: @phaberest, please write your own answer. It should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 124):

[String.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) does in fact remove newlines (and all other whitespace). Maybe it didn't used to? It definitely does at the time of writing. From the linked documentation (emphasis added):

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of a string. Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) *and all the line terminator characters (LF, CR, etc.).*

---

If you want to trim all newlines plus other potential whitespace, you can use the following:

```
return str.trim();
```

If you want to *only* trim newlines, you can use a solution that targets newlines specifically.

Comment: Maybe it was an IE issue? Looks like `trim` is [only IE 9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Browser_compatibility), but heaven help you if you're supporting IE 8 at this point. ;^D

Comment: That's definitely a possibility :)

Comment: This is acceptable if you want to get rid of all whitespace... but if you need to just get rid of new lines and leave other white space sources this will fail.

Comment: @SpencerO'Reilly That's true, but the goal of the question is to remove newlines in addition to the other whitespace they were successfully removing. Removing only newlines can be helpful too, it's just not an answer to this question

Answer (score 6):

`/^\s+|\s+$/g` should catch anything. Your current regex may have the problem that if your linebreaks contain `\r` characters they wouldn't be matched.

Answer (score 2):

return str.trim().replace(/^\s\n+|\s\n+$/g,'')

if you use it like this then i will remove line break from start and end string