# How to remove a preceding line-break from a Javascript string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

This is the string I have:

```
"
Store: Tailor Shop (1)
Send complete welcome package
Datasheet was completed at 01.01.2000"
```

How can I convert it to

```
"Store: Tailor Shop (1)
Send complete welcome package
Datasheet was completed at 01.01.2000"
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string

or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572413/remove-line-breaks-from-start-and-end-of-string

Comment: `String.prototype.trim`

Comment: `trim` did it! I thought that was supposed to only remove white-space, resp. I wasn't aware that newline counts as white-space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
string.replace(/\n/, '')
```

Regex without `g` modifier would remove only the first newline character.